# Android Volley skipping the data

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, android-volley

Actually I am using Volley  library to insert data into google sheet and its working fine for one or 2  row data sending  on one click but when I am sending more then two row of data for inserting into google sheet then its skipping the some row like some the out of 5 row its entered only 2 or 3 row if I am sending approx  10 row data at a time then also it is inserting 2 0r 3 some time 4 5 row of data . I just want to insert all row data in same sequence as I am sending . Please help me where I am wrong actually I am new In android. Thanks in advance.

```
public class AdddatatoGSheet {
    final Context context ;

    public AdddatatoGSheet(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public void   addItemToSheet(String USER_NAME,String Party,String Address,String State,String GSTIN, String Mobile, String EMAIL,String Closing_Balance,String ITEM,String GST,String CESS,String HSN,String SALE_RATE, String PUR_RATE,String QTY,String AMT,String GST_AMT,String CESS_AMT,String TOTAL)
    {

//        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog .show(context,"Adding Item","Please wait");
//        final String name = editTextItemName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String USER_NAMES = USER_NAME;
        final String PartyS = Party;
        final String AddressS = Address;
        final String StateS = State;
        final String GSTINS = GSTIN;
        final String MobileS = Mobile;
        final String EMAILS = EMAIL;
        final String Closing_BalanceS = Closing_Balance;
        final String ITEMS = ITEM;
        final String GSTS = GST;
        final String CESSS = CESS;
        final String HSNS = HSN;
        final String SALE_RATES = SALE_RATE;
        final String PUR_RATES = PUR_RATE;
        final String QTYS = QTY;
        final String AMTS = AMT;
        final String GST_AMTS = GST_AMT;
        final String CESS_AMTS = CESS_AMT;
        final String TOTALS = TOTAL;




        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxEI2Zua_79qLkUpMSpfyFjNEshYti8wPD34ZFrmsy45tLGJbE/exec",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();

                parmas.put("action","addItem");

                parmas.put("USER_NAME",USER_NAMES);
                parmas.put("Party",PartyS);
                parmas.put("Address",AddressS);
                parmas.put("State",StateS);
                parmas.put("GSTIN",GSTINS);
                parmas.put("Mobile",MobileS);
                parmas.put("EMAIL",EMAILS);
                parmas.put("Closing_Balance",Closing_BalanceS);
                parmas.put("ITEM",ITEMS);
                parmas.put("GST",GSTS);
                parmas.put("CESS",CESSS);
                parmas.put("HSN",HSNS);
                parmas.put("SALE_RATE",SALE_RATES);
                parmas.put("PUR_RATE",PUR_RATES);
                parmas.put("QTY",QTYS);
                parmas.put("AMT",AMTS);
                parmas.put("GST_AMT",GST_AMTS);
                parmas.put("CESS_AMT",CESS_AMTS);
                parmas.put("TOTAL",TOTALS);

                return parmas;
            }
        };
        int socketTimeOut = 20000;

        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        queue.add(stringRequest);


    }


}
```

Here I am calling the method addItemToSheet.

```
  private class adddata extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>, Integer, String> {
        
      private String resp;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>... params) {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultlist;
            resultlist = params[0];
            for (int i=0;i<resultlist.size();i++) {


                HashMap<String, String> hmap = resultlist.get(i);

                String a = hmap.get("snipervalues");
                String b = hmap.get("snipervalues2");
                String c = hmap.get("addrs");
                String d = hmap.get("states");
                String ee = hmap.get("gstins");
                String f = hmap.get("mob");
                String g = hmap.get("emails");
                String h = hmap.get("c_blncs");
                String ii = hmap.get("snumber");
                String j = hmap.get("gstid1");
                String k = hmap.get("cessid1");
                String l = hmap.get("hsnid1");
                String m = hmap.get("SaleRate1");
                String n = hmap.get("purrateid1");
                String o = hmap.get("qtyid1");
                String p = hmap.get("amtid1");
                String q = hmap.get("gstamtid1");
                String r = hmap.get("cessamtid1");
                String s = hmap.get("totalid1");
                try {
                    String aa = a;
                    String bb = b;
                    String cc = c;
                    String dd = d;
                    String eee = ee;
                    String ff = f;
                    String gg = g;
                    String hh = h;
                    String iii = ii;
                    String jj = j;
                    String kk = k;
                    String ll = l;
                    String mm = m;
                    String nn = n;
                    String oo = o;
                    String pp = p;
                    String qq = q;
                    String rr = r;
                    String ss = s;
                    Log.d("value is ", aa + bb + cc + dd + eee + ff + gg + hh);
                    Log.d("value is new ", bb);
                    Log.d("value is ", oo);
                    adddatatoGSheet.addItemToSheet(aa, bb, cc, dd, eee, ff, gg, hh, iii, jj, kk, ll, mm, nn, oo, pp, qq, rr, ss);


//                   
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Submit fail msz", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            String s2 = Boolean.toString(true);
            return s2;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(selectparty.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
//            finalResult.setText(result);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(selectparty.this,
                    "ProgressDialog",
                    "Inserting Data to "+" GSheet...");
        }



    }
```

And here is my code for without using AsyncTask . Using this method I am getting the same issue.

```
public void   addItemToSheet(String USER_NAME,String Party,String Address,String State,String GSTIN, String Mobile, String EMAIL,String Closing_Balance,String ITEM,String GST,String CESS,String HSN,String SALE_RATE, String PUR_RATE,String QTY,String AMT,String GST_AMT,String CESS_AMT,String TOTAL)
    {

        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog .show(context,"Adding Item","Please wait");

        final String USER_NAMES = USER_NAME;
        final String PartyS = Party;
        final String AddressS = Address;
        final String StateS = State;
        final String GSTINS = GSTIN;
        final String MobileS = Mobile;
        final String EMAILS = EMAIL;
        final String Closing_BalanceS = Closing_Balance;
        final String ITEMS = ITEM;
        final String GSTS = GST;
        final String CESSS = CESS;
        final String HSNS = HSN;
        final String SALE_RATES = SALE_RATE;
        final String PUR_RATES = PUR_RATE;
        final String QTYS = QTY;
        final String AMTS = AMT;
        final String GST_AMTS = GST_AMT;
        final String CESS_AMTS = CESS_AMT;
        final String TOTALS = TOTAL;




        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxEI2Zua_79qLkUpMSpfyFjNEshYti8wPD34ZFrmsy45tLGJbE/exec",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(context,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();

                parmas.put("action","addItem");
                parmas.put("USER_NAME",USER_NAMES);
                parmas.put("Party",PartyS);
                parmas.put("Address",AddressS);
                parmas.put("State",StateS);
                parmas.put("GSTIN",GSTINS);
                parmas.put("Mobile",MobileS);
                parmas.put("EMAIL",EMAILS);
                parmas.put("Closing_Balance",Closing_BalanceS);
                parmas.put("ITEM",ITEMS);
                parmas.put("GST",GSTS);
                parmas.put("CESS",CESSS);
                parmas.put("HSN",HSNS);
                parmas.put("SALE_RATE",SALE_RATES);
                parmas.put("PUR_RATE",PUR_RATES);
                parmas.put("QTY",QTYS);
                parmas.put("AMT",AMTS);
                parmas.put("GST_AMT",GST_AMTS);
                parmas.put("CESS_AMT",CESS_AMTS);
                parmas.put("TOTAL",TOTALS);

                return parmas;
            }
        };
        int socketTimeOut = 500000;// u can change this .. here it is 50 seconds

        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        queue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

This is my google apps script for inserting data into google sheet, do i need to change anything here?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v0X41-iWPt0QhCwSi8xWO8R8T0HmHj22vc_NcYgsDSk/edit#gid=0");

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Item11'); // be very careful ... it is the sheet name .. so it should match 


function doPost(e){
var action = e.parameter.action;

if(action == 'addItem'){
  return addItem(e);

}

}





function addItem(e){

var date =  new Date();
  
//var timeStamp = date.getTime();  

var currentTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();

var id  =  sheet.getLastRow(); // Item1

//var itemName = e.parameter.itemName;
//var brand = e.parameter.brand;
  var USER_NAME = e.parameter.USER_NAME;
  var Party = e.parameter.Party;
  var Address = e.parameter.Address;
  var State = e.parameter.State;
  var GSTIN = e.parameter.GSTIN;
  var Mobile = e.parameter.Mobile;
  var EMAIL = e.parameter.EMAIL;
  var Closing_Balance = e.parameter.Closing_Balance;
  var ITEM = e.parameter.ITEM;
  var GST = e.parameter.GST;
  var CESS = e.parameter.CESS;
  var HSN = e.parameter.HSN;
  var SALE_RATE = e.parameter.SALE_RATE;
  var PUR_RATE = e.parameter.PUR_RATE;
  var QTY = e.parameter.QTY;
  var AMT = e.parameter.AMT;
  var GST_AMT = e.parameter.GST_AMT;
  var CESS_AMT = e.parameter.CESS_AMT;
  var TOTAL = e.parameter.TOTAL;


sheet.appendRow([id,date,currentTime,USER_NAME,Party,Address,State,GSTIN,Mobile,EMAIL,Closing_Balance,ITEM,GST,CESS,HSN,SALE_RATE,PUR_RATE,QTY,AMT,GST_AMT,CESS_AMT,TOTAL]);

   return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);



}
```

Comment: You should not be using an `AsyncTask` not only is it deprecated but Volley already does its work on its own thread. So remove the entire `AsyncTask ` class then whatever you did in `onPostExecute` you do in Volley `onRepsonse`. For the `onPreExecute` and `doInBackground` you simply place that code before executing the Volley request

Comment: i have tried that one also ....first i have tried that one ,whatever you are saying ,but i get the same isssue after that i have implemented AsyncTask

Comment: The solution I suggested it correct don't use `AsyncTask`. The next suggestion on top of what I said is to put a `Log.d` statement in the `onErrorResponse` to see if there is any errors happening

Comment: i have tried showing 0 error . But some time I getiing this   "D/Volley: [337] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ]  0x5abc754f NORMAL 1> [lifetime=3538], [size=7], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]"

Comment: bro can you suggest anythings else?